# A Conceptual Intepretation of the identity

Tags: probability, permutations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, combinatorial-proofs

I came across the identity
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}}{2k+1} = \frac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$$ 
I tried it using the binomial theorem and integration and was able to prove it provided the identity
$$∫^1_0(1−x^2)^ndx=\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}$$
$$$$**MY TRY :** $$(1-x^2)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(x^2)^k $$
now integrating both sides gives us
$$∫^1_0(1−x^2)^ndx = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}}{2k+1} = \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!} $$
A little manipulation gives us $$\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!} = \frac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}$$
All this seems much calculative, is there a conceptual way of explaining the identity i.e.. via probability or permutation and combination?

Answer (score 2):

By the [binomial transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform) proving such identity is equivalent to proving

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-4)^k \binom{n}{k}\frac{k!^2}{(2k+1)!} = \frac{1}{2n+1}$$

which looks scarier, but is really not due to

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-4)^k \binom{n}{k}B(k+1,k+1)=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(4x(x-1))^k\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}(2x-1)^{2n}\,dx=\frac{1+(-1)^{2n}}{4n+2}. $$
Not really sure about a proper probabilistic interpretation, although.